# How to express random signal in MATLAB which is transmitted from transmitter to receiver

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, signal-detection, mimo

I am trying to model a random transmitted signal between transmitter (source) to receiver.

Specifically, the transmitter has $N_s = 1$ antenna and receiver has $N_r = 2$ antennas.

My query is that I am having doubt in writing MATLAB code for this system. I had written the code in two ways. So could any one pls tell whether the code written in (1) is correct or code written in (2) is correct.

```
xs = sqrt(v_S/2)*(randn(N_s,N_r)+1i*randn(N_s,N_r)); % ----(1)
```

where v_s is variance of transmitted signal such that v_s = 1, N_s and N_r are antennas at transmitter and receiver respectively.

```
xs = sqrt(v_S/2)*(randn(1,1)+1i*randn(1,1)); % ----(2)
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The variance of the transmitted signal `v_S` is completely unrelated to the variance of the noise at each receiver.

Comment: Ok... Thank u sir...but in many MATLAB codes I have seen the same way of modelling the signal